# Use registered domain with own dns

Tags: dns

I registered a domain. All I want is this domain resolve with my IP.
At the registrar I can set a nameserver for the domain. I set my IP.

From my understanding I now need to set up a authoritive nameserver on my machine, right?

Do you have a simple sample configuration for bind to do this and answer with the hosts own IP?

Thanks!

Comment: You certainly can do this but why would you want to? If DNS name resolution for your domain is important then use the name servers of the Registrar.

Comment: Is this a static address?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'M trying to map a registered domain (mydomain.com) to a dynamic host domain (mydomain.dyndns.com). Problem is, that the registrar dont let me set a IP or other Domain to foward, but I should set nameservers.
When I wanted to host it by an external hoster I would set that to the hosters nameserver. But I want host it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do what you want to do without trying to host your own nameservers.

Go to [cloudflare.com](https://www.cloudflare.com/) and sign up with an account. Then add your domain to the panel and follow the instructions. It will give you two name servers that you need to change on your domain registrar.

You can now use cloudflare as your DNS service.

After that, set up a CNAME record that points "@"(@ represents the root domain) to mydomain.dyndns.com. That way your domain will always point to your home IP.

You might have to delete the current root record on cloudflare to do so.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll give that a try tomorrow. Found my problem, though. The registrar alwys gave me a not configuered message. It needed the tcp port 53 open, too, for first time SOA query. Now they accept my dns zone authority.